# Android turn on the screen

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I making the application where an activity launch is scheduled by AlarmManager. I would like to appear even if the screen is turned off and device is locked.

To achive this a set the Window flags

```
final Window win = getWindow();
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

And try to obtain lock for the screen

```
if(_lock == null)
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)App.getAppContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    _lock = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "ScreenOn");
    _lock.acquire();
}
```

The _lock is PowerManager.WakeLock which is released in onPause

```
protected void onPause()
{
     if(_lock != null)
     {
          _lock.release();
     }
}
```

This code is executed in onCreate and onRestart. Everything works OK if the activity is not launched yet.

But if it was launched earlier the screen is not turned off.

- onRestart is called first
- onResume is then called
- onPause is called immediately

So the activity is not launched. My question is how to turn on the screen in such situation. (I am using API 15).

Comment: Post more of your code - all of it. What - where is _lock ? and you probably mean "the screen is not turned ***on***"

Comment: So lock is a _private static member_ ? Are you SURE that _Everything works OK if the activity is not launched yet_ ? Even when the phone is alseep ? Try to increase the initial alarm time - I bet the activity won't work. When I say more code I mean also the Alarm and receiver for the alarm - you are using a receiver for the ararm no ? And _again, you probably mean "the screen is not turned **on**"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the solution. I created a new activity which will be trying to turn on the screen in the `onCreate()` and then wait until it is turned on. When the screen is ok it will launch the activity which should be displayed. To make the Android always create this activity

```
public class TurnOnScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (pm.isScreenOn()) openActivity();
        else {
            registerReceiver(mScreenOnReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
            reciever_registered = true;
            turnScreenOn();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (reciever_registered) {
            unregisterReceiver(mScreenOnReceiver);
            reciever_registered = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean reciever_registered = false;
    private final BroadcastReceiver mScreenOnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            openActivity();
        }
    };

    private void openActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        // ....
        finish();
    }

    private void turnScreenOn() {
        final Window win = getWindow();
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

I am still looking for explanations why the screen is not turned on in onRestart.

Comment: You should move your code in `onResume` and unregister on `onPause`

Comment: I mean the receiver register code - it should be in `onResume` and unregistration on pause : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887169/android-when-to-register-unregister-broadcast-receivers-created-in-an-activity

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of "The Lighted Green Room"?  Check out the code below, it may be what you're looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/ch-bfh-fbi-mobicomp-2011/source/browse/ch_simplix_android_repetitive_service/src/com/androidbook/longrun/LightedGreenRoom.java?spec=svn38&r=37

Answer (score 1):

Just use your code :

```
final Window win = getWindow();
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

in **onCreate()** only and remove all those other Activity-Cycle methods if they are not doing anything else then this.

I don't think you need any more code to use to perform it.

Comment: It works perfect only first time. But when I put this activity to background the next time it won't do anything.