# How to avoid recreation of Fragment inside getItem method of FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` and i am creating Fragments dynamically inside `getItem` method of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as follows and i want to avoid recreation of `Fragment` inside this method so that the application does not crash.

```
        @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.

        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

        switch (position) {
        case 0:                 
            fragment = new CourseOverViewFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new CourseSchedueListFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new CourseSchedueListFragment();
            break;
        case 3: 
            fragment = new CourseNoteListFragment();
            break;
        case 4:             
            fragment = new ProjectListFragment();
            break;
        default:
            Log.i(StudyManagerDataSource.LOG_TAG, "default");
            break;

        }

        return fragment;

    }
```

How ever i fond [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642237/1773155) usefull. But i am not able to assign **tag**
inside `getItem` method.

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to, because the `FragmentPagerAdapter` already attempts to find previously added fragments (by tag, for which the adapter uses a private method) for you. Only if none was found, `getItem()` will be called. With that being said, your application crash is probably the result of something else..

Comment: Ok i will debug it and will try my best to find the reason :)