# Could this way of managing fragments cause any problems?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a simple fragment navigation system, which makes it easy to keep instances of fragments on screen rotation.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(getLayoutId(), null, false);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final XmlResourceParser parser = getContext().getResources().getLayout(getLayoutId());
    try {
        int type;
        while ((type = parser.next()) != XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
                type != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {}
    final AttributeSet attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
    view.setLayoutParams(container.generateLayoutParams(attrs));
    return view;
}
```

The fragments use `setRetainInstance(true)` and this part of the code should fix the memory leak mentioned here: [Further understanding setRetainInstance(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640316/further-understanding-setretaininstancetrue/12641575#12641575)
Also on the restart of the activity when screen rotates the fragments are stored in bundle and then restored back from the bundle and one fragment is set as visible. Is it correct to load all fragments on app start and keep them in memory or should they be loaded only when required?

Comment: Any reason you want to retain the instance and not just recreate it on activity restart?

Comment: To keep the fragment data and also the progress if some code, for example: a timer, is running.

Comment: maybe you should probably isolate that information into a model and use the fragment as just UI that;s displaying that info ? I used do what you are doing but its a rabbit hole that will lead you into more bugs.