# Avoiding manually handling configuration changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-manifest, android-configchanges

This project is an extension of the Master/Detail flow template that can be found in Android Studio. The difference is that this application uses a single Activity and a ViewPager that manages three Fragments. The third Fragment is the Master (list) Fragment, which contains a clickable RecycleView. When a list item is clicked, it switches the Fragment with the Child (detail) Fragment.

While the project works, I'd like to avoid using `android:configChanges= "orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` in the manifest. How should I do this?

If the attribute is removed, mListener in ItemListFragment is destroyed along with ItemFragmentList when rotating but is never re-created when ItemListFragment is re-created. This results in nothing happening when clicking on a List item in Portrait mode.

My initial solution was to manually override the configuration change handling, which meant ItemListFragment was not destroyed when rotating the screen. `onConfigurationChanged()` and `populateViewForOrientation()` were added to re-inflate the layout. Surely there is a better solution than to manually override configuration handling.

Project available at: https://github.com/lukeallison/ViewPagerMasterDetail,
Video: http://tinypic.com/r/1zltyeq/9

BaseFragment.java

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public Bridge mBridget;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mBridget = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    }
}
```

Interface: Bridge.java

```
public interface Bridge {
    abstract void onBack();
}
```

ItemListFragment.java

```
public class ItemListFragment extends BaseFragment{

    private boolean mTwoPane = false;
    private PageFragmentListener mListener;

    public static ItemListFragment newInstance(PageFragmentListener listener) {
        ItemListFragment fragment = new ItemListFragment();
        fragment.mListener = listener;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
        initLayout(root);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        populateViewForOrientation(inflater, (ViewGroup) getView());
    }

    private void populateViewForOrientation(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        viewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        View subview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, viewGroup);

        initLayout(subview);
    }

    public void initLayout(View root) {
        View recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.item_list);

        mTwoPane = false;
        if (root.findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {        // R.layout.list_item is located "layout", "layout-land"..
            mTwoPane = true;            // currently loaded "layout-land/list_item".  landscape mode
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("List");
        assert recyclerView != null;
        setupRecyclerView((RecyclerView) recyclerView);
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS));
    }

    public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final List<DummyContent.DummyItem> mValues;

        public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DummyContent.DummyItem> items) {
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_list_content, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
            holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
            holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

            // One row of List.  define click event
            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mTwoPane) {     // landscape mode
                        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString(Constants.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                        ItemTwoDetailFragment fragment = ItemTwoDetailFragment.newInstance();
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

                        // show detail fragment to right side of screen
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                                .commit();
                    } else {    // portrait mode
                        if (mListener!=null)
                            mListener.onSwitchToNextFragment(holder.mItem.id);      // switch detail fragment
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public final View mView;
            public final TextView mIdView;
            public final TextView mContentView;
            public DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
                mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

ItemOneDetailFragment.java

```
/**
 * A fragment representing a single Item detail screen.
 * on handsets.
 */
public class ItemOneDetailFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

    /*
    Listener for switch fragment
     */
    private PageFragmentListener mListener;

    public static ItemOneDetailFragment newInstance(PageFragmentListener listener) {
        ItemOneDetailFragment fragment = new ItemOneDetailFragment();
        fragment.mListener = listener;
        return fragment;
    }

    public ItemOneDetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(Constants.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(Constants.ARG_ITEM_ID)); // Get selected Item ID to show details
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_one_detail, container, false);

        // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
        if (mItem != null) {

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle(mItem.content);
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_ab_back_material);
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mBridget.onBack();
                }
            });

            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail)).setText(mItem.details);    // show details
        }

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

ItemTwoDetailFragment.java

```
// for landscape orientation
public class ItemTwoDetailFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;


    public static ItemTwoDetailFragment newInstance() {
        return new ItemTwoDetailFragment();
    }

    public ItemTwoDetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(Constants.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(Constants.ARG_ITEM_ID));     // Get selected item to show details
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_two_detail, container, false);

        // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
        if (mItem != null) {
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail)).setText(mItem.details);        // show details
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Bridge{

    private ViewPager viewPager = null;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    PageChangeListener mListener = new PageChangeListener();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mListener);       // Page Change Listener

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mListener.getCurrentPage()==2 && mAdapter.mFragment instanceof ItemOneDetailFragment) {     // current page is Tab-3, current fragment is detail fragment
            mAdapter.mListener.onSwitchToNextFragment("0");     // show List fragment
            return;     // prevent to finish app.
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    // Do the same thing as the back button - go back to ItemListFragment
    // Only when in ItemOneDetailFragment
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mListener.getCurrentPage() == 2 && mAdapter.mFragment instanceof ItemOneDetailFragment) {     // current page is Tab-3, current fragment is detail fragment
                mAdapter.mListener.onSwitchToNextFragment("0");     // show List fragment
//                return;     // prevent to finish app.
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        onBackPressed();
    }
}

class PageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {
    private int currentPage;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        currentPage = position;     // current selected page
    }

    public final int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }
}

/**
 * Fragment Page Adapter
 */
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    public BaseFragment mFragment;

    /**
     *  PageFragmentListener for switching fragment.
     */
    public PageFragmentListener mListener = new PageFragmentListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSwitchToNextFragment(final String id) {
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit();
            if (mFragment instanceof ItemListFragment){     // current fragment is List Fragment
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(Constants.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);     // selected item id
                mFragment = ItemOneDetailFragment.newInstance(mListener);       // switch detail fragment
                mFragment.setArguments(arguments);
            }else{      // DetailFragment
                mFragment = ItemListFragment.newInstance(mListener);    // => switch list fragment
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();     // notify changes
        }
    };

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)      // Tab-1
            return FragmentA.newInstance();

        if (position == 1)      // Tab-2
            return FragmentB.newInstance();

        if (position == 2) {    // Tab-3
            if (mFragment==null)    // first time => create list fragment
                mFragment = ItemListFragment.newInstance(mListener);

            return mFragment;
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {    // Tab-1
            return "Tab 1";
        }
        if (position == 1) {    // Tab-2
            return "Tab 2";
        }
    if (position == 2) {        //Tab-3
            return "Tab 3";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {     // Count of Tabs
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        Log.i("Adapter", "ItemPosition>>>" + object.toString());
        if (object instanceof ItemListFragment && mFragment instanceof ItemOneDetailFragment) {     //  fragment changed
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        if (object instanceof ItemOneDetailFragment && mFragment instanceof ItemListFragment) {     // fragment changed
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }
}
```

Interface: PageFragmentListener.java

```
public interface PageFragmentListener {
    void onSwitchToNextFragment(String id);
}
```

Log: With attribute added to Manifest.xml

```
First instantiation 
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: newInstance
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreate()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreateView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: initLayout
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: setupRecyclerView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onBindViewHolder

ClickItem
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onClick(): single pane
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: removed fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: is instance of List Fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemOneDetailFragment: newInstance
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>FragmentB{41dd3810 #1 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:1}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>ItemListFragment{41df1528 #2 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:2}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onStop()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroyView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroy()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()

Back
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: removed fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: is instance of Detail Fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: newInstance
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>FragmentB{41dd3810 #1 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:1}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>ItemOneDetailFragment{41e896a8 #2 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:2}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreate()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreateView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: initLayout
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: setupRecyclerView()

Rotate
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onConfigurationChanged
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: populateViewForOrientation
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: initLayout
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: setupRecyclerView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onBindViewHolder

ClickItemLand
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onClick(): mTwoPane

Rotate
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onConfigurationChanged
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: populateViewForOrientation
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: initLayout
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: setupRecyclerView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onBindViewHolder

ClickIemPortrait
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onClick(): single pane
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: removed fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: is instance of List Fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemOneDetailFragment: newInstance
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>FragmentB{41dd3810 #1 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:1}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>ItemListFragment{41ea8b68 #2 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:2}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onStop()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroyView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroy()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()
```

Log: Without attribute

```
First instantiation 
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: newInstance
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreate()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreateView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: initLayout
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: setupRecyclerView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onBindViewHolder

ClickItem
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onClick(): single pane
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: removed fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: is instance of List Fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemOneDetailFragment: newInstance
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>FragmentB{41dd4758 #1 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:1}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>ItemListFragment{41ded998 #2 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:2}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onStop()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroyView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroy()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()

Back
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: removed fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/MyAdapter: is instance of Detail Fragment
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: newInstance
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>FragmentB{41dd56b8 #1 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:1}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail I/Adapter: ItemPosition>>>ItemOneDetailFragment{41e830b8 #2 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:2}
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreate()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreateView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: initLayout
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: setupRecyclerView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onBindViewHolder

Rotate
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onSaveInstanceState()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onStop()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroyView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroy()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreate()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreateView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: initLayout
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: setupRecyclerView()

ClickItemLand
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onClick(): mTwoPane

Rotate
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onSaveInstanceState()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onStop()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroyView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onDestroy()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onPause()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreate()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onCreateView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: initLayout
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: setupRecyclerView()
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-16 .../com.allison.viewpagermasterdetail D/ItemListFragment: onBindViewHolder

ClickIemPortrait
// nothing happens
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have several issues needed to be fixed.

First your link to `mListener` in `SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter` gets broken when activity is recreated. Hence you need to restore that connection after activity is recreated. To do that you need to do following fixes.

**Main Activity**

Make the `PageFragmentListener` accessible to outside by declaring it as a property

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Bridge {
    ...
    PageChangeListener mListener = new PageChangeListener();
    //keep a reference to listener, need to access this from fragment
    PageFragmentListener mPageFragmentListener;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //set the listener
        mPageFragmentListener = mAdapter.mListener;
        ....
    }

}
```

**ItemListFragment**

Override `onActivityCreated`method in `ItemListFragment` and restore `mListener` by accessing it from the activity

```
public class ItemListFragment extends BaseFragment{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if(activity instanceof MainActivity) {
            mListener = ((MainActivity)activity).mPageFragmentListener;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now your `mListener` will be always set correctly when activity is recreated. But you have to do few more fixes for smoother operation.

Your `MyAdapter` keep reference to an instance of fragment called `mFragment`. When activity recreated you need to restore this variable as well. Hence you need to modify your `MyAdapter` constructor as below.

```
public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mFragmentManager = fm;
    List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
    if(fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment f : fragments) {
            if (f instanceof ItemListFragment || f instanceof ItemOneDetailFragment) {
                mFragment = (BaseFragment) f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At this point your code should work. But it will crash when you rotate your device while viewing the detail of a list item. This happens because you add child fragments to the activity directly from your `ItemListFragment` using the Activity's `FragmentManager`. Instead use childFragmentManager from Fragment itself.

```
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mTwoPane) {     // landscape mode
        ...
        // show detail fragment to right side of screen
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
            .commit();
        } else {    // portrait mode
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your final step please? What code should I remove in order to replace it with the code using ChildFragmentManager?

Comment: Replace getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() with getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thank you so much. Any other suggestions on how to make my app less bloated?

Comment: Great, don't know how to give any simple suggestions. However read more content on Fragments and it's life cycle. Understanding that will help you write more compact and efficient code

Comment: Could I use ChildFragment for the Portrait version of ItemDetailFragment as well?

Comment: Yes you can, But then you may need to change big part of your current implementation. Just remember you need ChildFragmentManager if you embed Fragments inside other Fragments. (It is what you do in your landscape layout). But in your portrait layout you are not doing such thing. In that case you just ask the parent Activity to change the Fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106516/discussion-between-luke-allison-and-dishan).

Comment: The app crashes if I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child. This occurs after rotating the screen twice and then clicking on a list item in portrait mode. It refers to this line:                            mListener.onSwitchToNextFragment(holder.mItem.id); Any ideas?

Comment: @LukeAllison In short you don't need FragmentStatePagerAdapter here. You need it if you have large number of fragments. FragmentStatePagerAdapter destroys fragments and restore them as needed. This might cause the problem you face. In your case you have fixed amount of fragments. So it's an unnecessary overhead to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: I'm merging this code into another project that uses FragmentStatePagerAdapter and it would be much easier to make this code use FragmentStatePagerAdapter than make the larger project use FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: ItemOneDetailFragment is created with newInstance() and passed a bundle when I click on an item in ItemListFragment. However, even though onDetach, onDestroyFragment and onDestroy has been previously called on ItemOneDetailFragment, it is still attached when I'm trying to inflate it again. I assume this is what the error refers to: ScrollView can host only one direct child. Although I can't seem to remove the View. Ideas?

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter saves and recreate Its fragments. Hence it is possible that your Fragment is already created by FragmentStatePagerAdapter when you try to create new one. As far as I know I don't see a simple solution here. If I were you I will change the Way I display the detail fragment in portrait layout. Instead of using PagerAdapter to create the detail fragment. I'll create a new activity called DetailActivity that contain the DetailFragment and start it from MainActivity.

Comment: Omitting your change of getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() to getChildFragmentManager() fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using the MVP pattern might help since Presenters can be created in a way such that they survive configuration changes. I recently came across a series of blog posts aimed at explaining such an implementation of the MVP pattern. I'm sure they'll be of help to you.

Blogs posts: [Part 1](http://blog.bradcampbell.nz/mvp-presenters-that-survive-configuration-changes-part-1/) [Part 2](http://blog.bradcampbell.nz/mvp-presenters-that-survive-configuration-changes-part-2/)