# how to keep title not changing it when orientation happen to default title android

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer, orientation, onsaveinstancestate

I created activity has multiple fragments opens by clicking in menu items in navigation drawer, the problem I face is when I select some item and the relevant fragment opens with the right title in toolbar then rotate the app the fragment stays at it is(which what I want and what I did , I used savedInstanceState to keep it) the title in toolbar changes to the default one!

I didn't know how to keep the title with the fragments

here is the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

TextView header;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    header = findViewById(R.id.header);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setupDrawer(toolbar);

    if(savedInstanceState==null) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        header.setText("Home");
    }

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        ab.setTitle(null);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
    }

}

private void setupDrawer(Toolbar toolbar) {

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();


    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            header.setText("Home");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            header.setText("Settings");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_about:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            header.setText("About app");
            break;

    }


    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}


}
```

and here the xml for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content"

            />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer">


    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my toolbar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:elevation="0dp">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="28sp"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I searched and found some solutions but didn't worked for me or maybe I didn't know how to do it right, so please help, thanks in advance

Comment: try to call the setText() in the onRestart() lifecCycle fun

Comment: @alserdar I tried its not working

Comment: i think the problem in the first  header.setText("Home");
try to add else or something

Comment: even if I remove it nothing will happen(I mean header.setText("Home")), if I add else what should be there ? @alserdar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, actually I tried it before but I was doing something wrong, now I new what I did .. the solution I find is to use the following code :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString(STATE_SELECTED_KEY, title);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    title = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_SELECTED_KEY, "Home");
    header.setText(title);
}
```

the value of variable title is changing on menu item selected, and then we just save it onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and call onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) to get it back

thanks to this [solution I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40245363/2510116)

Answer (score 0):

1-
**Try declaring saveEnabled = "true" in your Text inside xml layout .**

2- **try this :**

```
header = findViewById(R.id.header);

    if (myNewBoolean) {
        tvNowUsedFiltres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

3- **try this too :**

put this in your Fragment onCreate()

```
setRetainInstance(boolean)
```

Comment: what is myNewBoolean ? I can understand its boolean variable but whats its value ? and can you explain what tvNowUsedFiltres ? and why we should make it visible

Comment: you wrote 1, 2 and 3 are those steps or everyone is a different solution ? I tried 1 and 3 and still nothing happen, I didn't use 2 because I didn't get it

Comment: Could u try this in  onCreateViewMethod  >>

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    if (container == null) // must put this in
        return null;
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.<layout>, container, false);
}

Comment: I don't think that will help