# Crash in Fragment when using viewPager inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, exception, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager inside Fragment. I am getting following crash report in Crashlytics. Please help out how to resolve this issue

```html
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Child FragmentManager of MovieFragmentBase{9fa4a22 #1 id=0x7f0a0468 MovieFragmentBase} was not destroyed and this fragment is not retaining instance
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDetach (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (Unknown Source)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (Unknown Source)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:822)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5736)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:910)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:771)
```

Please check the code of viewPagerAdapter that I am using inside MovieFragmentBase.

```html
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `ViewPagerAdapter` code here?

Comment: @dr3k I have added the viewPagerAdapter code in my question. Please check the edited question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `setRetainInstance(true);` in your `onCreate()` of your `MovieFragmentBase`, May be this will help you

For more information about `setRetainInstance`  follow below link

[Further understanding setRetainInstance(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640316/further-understanding-setretaininstancetrue)