# Using findFragmentById with a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My app has a list and detail view, where I allow the user to swipe between the different detail views, using a `ViewPager` in portrait.  In landscape, I show both fragments on the screen.

I'm having an issue where, when the device is rotated, the icons are duplicating themselves over and over in the `Actionbar`.  I've learned that I'm probably creating new fragments whenever the device is rotated and I should be checking if the fragment is in the `FragmentManager` and then create a new instance if it isn't.

I am able to do that easily using the landscape layout, however, I'm not sure how to check if the fragment exists in portrait mode, using the `ViewPager`. Do I do that in `getItem()` of the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

This is the code I'm using:

```
public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private static List<Integer> mIds;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager); //view pager exists, so we are using the portait layout

        if (mViewPager != null)
        {
            mIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            mIds.add(0);
            mIds.add(1);
            mIds.add(2);
        }
        else //in landscape
        {           
            ListFragment lf = (ListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentList);

            if (lf == null)
                lf = new ListFragment();

            DetailFragment df = (DetailFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentDetail);

            if (df == null)
            {
                df = new DetailFragment();
                df.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());   
            }

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentList, lf).commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentDetail, df).commit();
        }
    }       

    private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {  

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
             super(fm);  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {        
            //can't use getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById() here because I get a "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method" error
            if (index == 0)
                return ListFragment.newInstance();
            else            
                return DetailFragment.newInstance(mIds.get(index-1));
        }  

        @Override
        public int getCount() {  
             return 4;
        }
   }  
}
```

**Main Layout (portrait)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
     />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Layout (landscape)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
>
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragmentList"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDetail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

**List Fragment**

```
public class ListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements DialogKeywordAddListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public static ListFragment newInstance() {

        return new ListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listing, container, false);
    }
}
```

**Detail Fragment**

```
public class DetailFragment extends SherlockListFragment
{
    private int mId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public static DetailFragment newInstance() {

        DetailFragment df = new DetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id", id);
        df.setArguments(bundle);

        return df;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null)
            mId = getArguments().getInt("id");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164126/retain-the-fragment-object-while-rotating) solution seemed to work for me.  Just setting:

```
    super.onCreate(null);
```

in `onCreate` of the `Activity` solved my fragment issue.

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea, gutting many other features in the process.