# refresh fragment at reload or after rotating

Tags: android

I wrote the following code fragment regenerate when the screen is rotated.

the fragment setArguments is a "java.lang.IllegalStateException" error occurs.

What better way is there to do?

Reference of:[retain the fragment object while rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164126/retain-the-fragment-object-while-rotating)

Reference of:[refresh fragment at reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String tag = "my_fragment";
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment f = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
    if(f == null) { //or if(null == savedInstanceState){
        //create Fragment
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment homeFragment = new Home();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainFragement, homeFragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else {
        //renew Fragment
        Bundle newArgs = //want to renew Args
        f.setArguments(newArgs);

        ft.detach(f);
        ft.attach(f);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

01-24 16:00:54.905: E/VideoPlayerActivity.java # onNewIntent:319(22727): Fragment already active
01-24 16:00:54.905: E/VideoPlayerActivity.java # onNewIntent:319(22727): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active
01-24 16:00:54.905: E/VideoPlayerActivity.java # onNewIntent:319(22727):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setArguments(Fragment.java:551)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me.
I was resolved by myself, Thank you.

```
} else {
    //renew Fragment
    f.getArguments().putInt(XXXXXXX, x);
    f.getArguments().putSerializable(XXXXXXX, X);

    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(f);
    ft.attach(f);
    ft.commit();
}
```