# Why getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag returns null after rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I'm trying to making an app that contain `Activity` and two `Fragments`. Any Fragment can call interface method that implemented by `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onFragmentRequest(final String fragmentTag) {

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {
              // simulate network connection
              Thread.sleep(3000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

                if(fragment == null)
                    Log.d(TAG, "fragment is null");
                else {
                    if(fragment instanceof OnFragmentResponse)
                        ((OnFragmentResponse) fragment).onFragmentResponse();
                }
              }
          });
      }
  }).start();

}
```

But problem is when after calling `onFragmentRequest` and make device rotation `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)` returns `null`

All fragments I replace and adding to back stack and after all I call `commit` method and `manager.executePendingTransactions()` but it no help

Logs before or without rotation:

```
02-07 16:39:12.202 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: onFragmentRequest: fragmentTag = NewsFragment
02-07 16:39:12.203 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: getSupportFragmentManager.entryCount = 1
02-07 16:39:12.203 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/NewsFragment: onFragmentResponse success
```

Logs when call `onFragmentRequest` and device rotation:

```
02-07 16:39:23.454 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: onFragmentRequest: fragmentTag = NewsFragment
02-07 16:39:23.454 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: getSupportFragmentManager.entryCount = 1
02-07 16:39:23.454 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: fragment is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTranscation();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I doing it by default. I must edit my answer.

Comment: @Trancer Are you receiving something in fragmentTag?

Comment: Yes, something like this: `MainActivity: onFragmentRequest: fragmentTag = NewsFragment
MainActivity: getSupportFragmentManager.entryCount = 1
MainActivity: fragment is null`

Comment: See this I think that can helps with your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164126/retain-the-fragment-object-while-rotating

Comment: OK, I was edited my post and show full code of my problematic method

Comment: For those who searching an a solution: https://github.com/alexjlockwood/adp-worker-fragments